# Unity Actions/events/delegates confusion

Tags: unity-game-engine, events, delegates, action, game-development

Having some trouble setting up Actions in Unity for a small project I'm working on. Would love to get some guidance as I'm a little confused.

basic setup is:

I click a ui button element to move the player character in a certain direction. i.e. forward, back, left, right.

```
    void onMoveForwardClicked()
    {
        Actions.OnPlayerMoved(Directions.Forward);
    }
```

I have a class I've called Actions that looks like this

```
public static class Actions
{
    public static Action<Directions> OnPlayerMoved;
}
```

My player script has a method that takes an enum parameter of directions and uses a switch statement to set the new position for a 2d array I use as my map/arena.

```
    public void MovePlayer(Directions direction)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case Directions.Forward:
                    _NewPositionInRing.x -= 1;
                    break;
            case Directions.Backward:
                    _NewPositionInRing.x += 1;
                    break;
            case Directions.Left:
                    _NewPositionInRing.y -= 1;
                    break;
            case Directions.Right:
                    _NewPositionInRing.y += 1;
                    break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

My map class instantiates the 10x10 2D array and sets an initial position for the player. The map class also has a method to set the players new position and reset the old position to 0 (empty space)

```
    public void setNewPlayerPositions(Vector2Int oldPos, Vector2Int newPos, int playerID)
    {
        Debug.Log("oldPos: X:" + oldPos.x + ", Y:" + oldPos.y);
        Debug.Log("newPos: X:" + newPos.x + ", Y:" + newPos.y);
 
        Player1Postions = new Vector2Int(newPos.x, newPos.y);
        mapArray[newPos.x, newPos.y] = playerID;
        mapArray[oldPos.x, oldPos.y] = 0;
    }
```

I'm a little confused on how I can hook this ui button up such when clicked it updates the correct values using unity Actions.

I may be fundamentally misunderstanding how to do this, but I am open to learning so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I've followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fcI8W9NBEo but I get lost around the ~9 minute mark when multiple Listeners come into play and the parameters complicate.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have 3 steps while using an Action in C#: definition, listening and invoking.

First, define it. You already defined it with this line:

```
public static Action<Directions> OnPlayerMoved;
```

Second, listen to it. You are not listening. Imagine this like subscribing to a youtube channel. if you subscribed, then you can get notifications from the channel. So you should listen to your action like this:

```
Actions.OnPlayerMoved += OnPlayerMovedListenerMethod;

private void OnPlayerMovedListenerMethod(Directions direction)
{
    Debug.Log(direction);
}
```

Finally, you should invoke it. But you have already did.

```
Actions.OnPlayerMoved(Directions.Forward);
```

That's the basic. For further research, you can learn the these:

- **event** keyword
- **Func**
- **delegate** keyword